# Swift - Tableview not updating properly with search queries

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm using the search bar controller with a tableview. I'm fetching the contacts on my phone to populate the tableview. Here's my code for this part.

```
func fetchContacts(){

    let key = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: key)
    try! contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request) {(contact, stoppingPointer) in

        let name  = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)"
        let number = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue

        for numbero in contact.phoneNumbers {

            if let number = numbero.value as? CNPhoneNumber,
                let label = numbero.label {

                var contactToAppend = ContractStruct(givenName: name, number: number.stringValue)
                self.contacts.append(contactToAppend)
            }
        }
    }
        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

It retrieves the contact with different phone numbers properly and then displays in the tableview. I've also added multi selection on the tableview to be able to select multiple contacts to continue with my flow of the app.

My issue is when I'm searching for the contact in the search bar , it always gives me the wrong contacts in my tableview. It comes up with the same name always at the top. [Returns wrong contact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZAV4.png)

Now if I print my filteredcontact list , it returns the proper contact that should have been displayed but it is not displayed on the tableview. Here's my code for the search

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text! == "" {
        filteredContacts = contacts

    } else {
    // Filter the results
        filteredContacts = contacts.filter { $0.givenName.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased())
        }
    }

    print(filteredContacts)
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

And here's my full class:

```
class ContactsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var contactStore = CNContactStore()
    var contacts = [ContractStruct]()
    var filteredContacts = [ContractStruct]()

    var setSelectedItems: Set<Int> = []
    var searching = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self


        contactStore.requestAccess(for: .contacts) {(success, error) in

            if success {
                print("Authorisation Successful")
            }

            self.fetchContacts()


        }

        filteredContacts = contacts

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

         return filteredContacts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

             let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)

              if setSelectedItems.contains(indexPath.row) {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                    }

              else {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
                    }



              let contactToDisplay = contacts[indexPath.row]
              cell.textLabel?.text = contactToDisplay.givenName
              cell.detailTextLabel?.text = contactToDisplay.number


              return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if setSelectedItems.contains(indexPath.row) {
               setSelectedItems.remove(indexPath.row)
           } else {
               setSelectedItems.insert(indexPath.row)
           }
           tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

         print(setSelectedItems)
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchBar.text! == "" {
            filteredContacts = contacts

        } else {
        // Filter the results
            filteredContacts = contacts.filter { $0.givenName.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased())
            }
        }

        print(filteredContacts)
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        tableView.reloadData()

        }


    func fetchContacts(){

        let key = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: key)
        try! contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request) {(contact, stoppingPointer) in

            let name  = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)"
            let number = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue

            for numbero in contact.phoneNumbers {

                if let number = numbero.value as? CNPhoneNumber,
                    let label = numbero.label {

                    var contactToAppend = ContractStruct(givenName: name, number: number.stringValue)
                    self.contacts.append(contactToAppend)
                }
            }
        }
            tableView.reloadData()
    }




    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: just move `tableView.reloadData()` into `contactStore.enumerateContacts`'s scope's last line in `fetchContacts` function. This is an async process so if you look at it you should see the reload line called before `enumarateContacts`

Comment: @emrcftci It still gives the same output.

Comment: @emrcftci The name Kate Bell (Contact list from simulator) always comes up.

Comment: could you please try to replace `contacts[indexPath.row]` to `filteredContacts[indexPath.row]` in `cellForRowAt` function of tableView delegate?

Comment: @emrcftci Thank you, it works! , stupid mistake from my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `contacts[indexPath.row]` to `filteredContacts[indexPath.row]` in `cellForRowAt` function of tableView delegate.

Because your filtered results stored in `filteredContacts` and your `tableView` `delegate` functions use `filteredContacts`

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace `filteredContacts[indexPath.row]` in `cellForRowAt` for it to work.

Comment: Hi @Ziyaad, please accept your answer if that worked for you.

Comment: @MertŞimşek actually it is my answer :D please check the comments under the question

Comment: @emrcftci then, you should post it as an answer for being accepted :)